# "Plugins colliding with each other" when building Unity scene for WebGL

Tags: unity, soft-body-dynamics

I have a simple scene that looks like this:

[image]

It's using the free [DefKit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/50767) plugin to make the bunny a soft-body.

This works fine in Unity, I can play the scene and it's great.

However I can't build for WebGL. I'm getting the following error:

```
Plugin 'DefKit.dll' is used from several locations:
 Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86/DefKit.dll would be copied to <PluginPath>/DefKit.dll
 Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86_64/DefKit.dll would be copied to <PluginPath>/DefKit.dll
Plugin 'UTet.dll' is used from several locations:
 Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86_64/UTet.dll would be copied to <PluginPath>/UTet.dll
 Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86/UTet.dll would be copied to <PluginPath>/UTet.dll
Please fix plugin settings and try again.

UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions(String)
UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions(BuildTarget) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Plugins/PluginsHelper.cs:25)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and then it says

```
Plugins colliding with each other.
```

I'm really not sure how to go about fixing this. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.

---

**update**

after deleting the /x86 folder as advised in an answer, I get this error when building:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "E:\platform_fighter\platform-fighter\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.asm.js".
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:305)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:167)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string,System.Text.Encoding)
System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:587)
System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:582)
UnityEditor.WebGL.CodeAnalysisUtils.ReplaceDuplicates (System.String builtCodePath, Int32 interations) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/CodeAnalysisUtils.cs:145)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:589)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

---

**update 2**

another error!

```
Exception: E:\Unity5.0.0\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:98)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 arguments, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:281)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection`1 userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:272)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:126)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry, Boolean developmentBuild) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:39)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:560)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, delete the x86 directories.

- `Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86/`
- `Assets/AssetStore/DefKit/Plugins/x86/`

The problem is that WebGL is trying to copy the same dll (but different versions) into one location. It doesn't know which one to use. In this case x86 is likely for legacy support when building to other targets, you can remove it.

Comment: thank you, deleting this folder allowed the build to _look like_ it was proceeding, it went through all the steps like building assets, converting assemblies, etc. But the destination folder is empty. I have built for WebGl before so I know it works, and there are no errors, so I'm confused.

Comment: Actually there is another error. Do you mind taking a look at the update in the question?

Comment: Do a rebuild or reimport all your assets. Restart Unity. Etc. There's junk left over from previous failures.

Comment: Thanks again, but wouldn't you know it, there's another error. Mind taking a look at this last update to the question?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about that one. Google the error message, see what applies to your situation. Typically you'd ask one question per post, so you may want to move your latest to a new question.

Comment: I realize that, I suppose I was trying to cheat a little by throwing a couple in while i had a captive audience :)